# How to destructure useContext hook in Typescript with null default value?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I created context with null initial value that I am now accessing in other component.
However when I destructure it to access the variables form the context then I get ts error:

`Property 'users' does not exist on type 'GithubContextProps`

```
function UserResults() {
  const appContext = useContext(GithubContext)

  const { users, loading, fetchUsers } = appContext
  

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsers()
  }, [fetchUsers])

  if (!loading) {
    return (
      <div className='grid grid-cols-1 gap-8 xl:grid-cols-4 lg:grid-cols-3 md:grid-cols-2'>
        {users.map((user : User) => (
          <UserItem key={user.id} user={user} />
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  } else {
    return <Spinner />
  }
}
```

And here is where i created context:

```
export type User = {
  id: number;
  login: string;
  avatar_url: string;
}

interface GithubContextProps {
  users: User[];
  loading: boolean;
  fetchUsers: () => void;
}


const GithubContext = createContext<GithubContextProps | null>(null)
```

I tried solving this with using conditional checking whether `appContext` is not null but then useEffect will throw errors that it cannot be used conditionally in this component. Any idea how to solve it without resorting to turning off React strict mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
const { users, loading, fetchUsers } = appContext ?? {};
```

You'll get `undefined` when appContext is `null`.

Comment: Hmm it seems to solve the issue in question, but I get the issue inside `useEffect` where the TS error says: `Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.`

Comment: @AlexT Try checking if fetchUsers is available:

useEffect(() => {
    if (fetchUsers) {fetchUsers();}
  }, [fetchUsers])

or

useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsers?.();
  }, [fetchUsers])

Comment: Same goes for the `users` object later in the code as provided in the quetion. Complier will throw an error for it as it possible can be `undefined`

Comment: Same applies in case of `users`: `users?.map(...`

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
 const GithubContext = createContext<GithubContextProps | null>({{ users:[], loading:false, fetchUsers:null }});
```

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect`, and every other hook must always be called every time the component re-renders, so conditionally calling `useEffect` will not work. I would try placing the check inside the `useEffect` then place another check for our jsx:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (appContext) appContext.fetchUsers()
}, [fetchUsers])

if (!appContext || appContext.loading) return <Spinner />;
// you can then destructure
const { users, loading, fetchUsers } = appContext;
// ...
```

Or a more better solution, you can pass the context value as props to `<UserResults />` instead so that you'll only need to check on the parent component, which is arguably more cleaner

```
const Parent = () => {
  const appContext = useContext(GithubContext);
  if (!appContext) return <Spinner />;
  return <UserResults appContext={appContext} />;
}

const UserResults = ({ appContext }) => {
  const { users, loading, fetchUsers } = appContext;
  // ...
}
```